# Working With Enumeration Types: Listing, Comparing, and Building Histograms

Tags: haskell, enumeration

I've recently completed (for self study) a [homework assignment of some UPenn Haskell Course](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/hw/02-lists.pdf) of building a [Mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29) solver.

The assignment starts off with the definitions of

```
data Color = Red | Green |  Blue |  Yellow | Orange |  Purple deriving (Eq, Show)

type Code = [Color]
```

and involves various manipulations of enumeration types. Although I've managed to [complete the assignment](http://lpaste.net/160180), there were several parts where I felt my code was unnecessarily repetitive or inefficient:

1. For the purpose of enumerating all codes of length *n* (i.e., all Cartesian combinations of length *n* of `Color` values), I've used

   ```
   allColors = [Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Orange, Purple]
   ```

   This seems repetitive and brittle, as it's just all the possibilities of `Color`. Is there a way to singly define the enumerations, and then build a list from them? Conceptually, I'd like something like `allColors = listAll(Color)` (where the question is what is `listAll`).
2. Since many of the expressions contained `(if l == r then 1 else 0)` (where `l`, `r` are `Color`s), I've ended up writing a `boolToInt` function. Surely there's some way to compare two enumeration types and cast the result to an integer more easily, no? I.e., I'd like `Red == Red` to evaluate to 1, and `Red == Blue` to evaluate to 0.
3. Part of the solution requires building a histogram from a `Code`, which I did using

   ```
   countColor :: Color -> Code -> Int
   countColor _ [] = 0
   countColor c (r:rs) = (boolToInt (c == r)) + countColor c rs

   countColors :: Code -> [Int]
   countColors code = [countColor c code | c <- allColors]
   ```

   This seems both inefficient and verbose. Is there any shorter + more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If we define

```
data Color = Red | Green |  Blue |  Yellow | Orange | Purple
   deriving (Eq, Show, Enum, Bounded, Ord)
```

then we can use

```
> [minBound .. maxBound] :: [Color]
[Red,Green,Blue,Yellow,Orange,Purple]
```

2) To convert a boolean into an integer, we can use

```
> fromEnum True
1
> fromEnum False
0
```

3) For the histogram, we can start by sorting and grouping:

```
> import Data.List
> map (\xs -> (head xs, length xs)) . group . sort $ [Red, Red, Blue, Red]
[(Red,3),(Blue,1)]
```

adding zeros is left as an exercise.

Using an array instead of a list could improve the performance by removing a O(log n) factor, but I'd avoid that unless we know that performance really matters here.

Comment: Many thanks. I really like 1 + 2. Your 3 is shorter, too, but is logarithmic time, no? Perhaps it's the nature of Haskell (or functional languages in general), though.

Comment: @Ami yes, as I wrote. If you want O(n) time instead of O(n log n) time, you should use an array and a left fold. I wouldn't worry too much for that, unless you know the performance of this part of your code is critical.

Answer (score 3):

For 1. and 3. See [chi's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36665795/745903).

For 2. I'd suggest you avoid manually adding counters in recursive functions. It's generally more idiomatic in Haskell to use standard higher-order functions. For instance, `countColor` just gives you the length of the sublist fulfilling a predicate. Hence, I would implement it as

```
countColor c = length . filter (==c)
```

Similarly,

```
exactMatches ls rs = length . filter id $ zipWith (==) ls rs
```